# How do i use React Native to build a caller app without showing phone number?

Tags: react-native

My client wants to allow his staff to contact his customers without showing his customer's phone number.

I am thinking to build a caller app where my client and his staff both needs to download and install it on their phone.

function on their apps:
My client: he can save his customers' contact inside this app and the phone number will show on his side.
My client's staff: He can make call using this app and the phone number will not show on his phone at anytime.

I am able to make a phone call but how do i replace the default phone caller app inside their phone?